# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in |

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to figure it out by myself by looking at other people's problem related to this error. However, since I'm not a coder, I wasn't able to fix it myself.

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /homepages/30/d834969130/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Freiraum4ImmobilienundFinanzierung/wp-content/plugins/onoffice-for-wp-websites/plugin/EstateList.php on line 375

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /homepages/30/d834969130/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Freiraum4ImmobilienundFinanzierung/wp-content/plugins/onoffice-for-wp-websites/plugin/EstateList.php on line 376
```

This is the affected code:

```
$this->_currentEstate['id'] = $currentRecord['id']; (line 375)
$recordElements = $currentRecord['elements'];
$this->_currentEstate['mainId'] = $recordElements['mainLangId'] ??
$this->_currentEstate['id'];

if (false === $currentRecord) {
return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, one of these variables (depending on which line is which) is a boolean, not an array.

Comment: It would help to indicate which is line 375 or 376, the line that your error is occurring at. Your description says 375, but the copy/pasted error message says 376. Maybe your check to see whether `false === $currentRecord` should be done _before_ you try to use the contents of that array, rather than afterwards.

Comment: 375
$this->_currentEstate['id'] = $currentRecord['id'];

376
$recordElements = $currentRecord['elements'];

Thanks for the comments so far.

Comment: As I said above, what if you check to see if `false === $currentRecord` before trying to use the values in `$currentRecord`? Why would you check after you've used them?

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. Thank you so much!